# What template tags am I missing?

Tags: django-templates

```
def _simple_report_topic(self,section=None, visit_id=None, primary=''):

    status = []
    report_buckets = {}

    cvm = Cvm(visit_id=visit_id)
    ns = cvm.get_cvm_namespace()
    vmd = ns['vmd']
    assoc_instances = vmd.assoc_instances     

    all_factoids = []
    for ad in section['factoids']:
        all_factoids.extend(self.get_factoids(ad))

    for rt in self.report_topics:

        factoids = [f for f in all_factoids if f.report_topic and \
                    f.report_topic.ad == rt['ad'] and \
                    f.ad not in self.global_seen_factoids]

        # Figure out if we have data for this factoid.
        prs = PatientResponse.objects.filter(
            visit__id=visit_id,
            confirmation__in=self.valid_states,
            factoid__in=factoids,
            feature__ad=section['feature'],
            norm_value__gte=section['threshold'],
        ).order_by('-norm_value')

        if not prs:
            continue

        fv_ad = prs[0].feature_value
        # This flag controls when we show the title for this report topic.
        suppress_label = False

        render_data = []

        if not suppress_label:
            render_data.append(widgets.TopicTitleWidget(title=rt['text']))
            suppress_label = True

        for pr in prs:

            self.global_seen_factoids.add(pr.factoid.ad)
            # The result of the rendering will be a FactoidWidget.
            result = self.render_factoid(factoid=pr.factoid, visit_id=visit_id, primary=primary)
            if result:
                render_data.append(result) 

        if report_buckets.get(fv_ad):
            report_buckets[fv_ad].append(render_data)
        else:
            report_buckets[fv_ad] = [render_data]

    report_buckets = report_buckets.items()
    report_buckets.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y[0], x[0]))

    # Number the topics.
    counter = 1
    for key, value in report_buckets:
        for each_list in value:
            for item in each_list:
                if item.widget_type == 'TopicTitle':
                    item.title = '%s) %s' % (counter, capfirst(item.title))
                    counter += 1


    if not report_buckets:
        #print "report buckets are %s" % report_buckets
        #print "vmd.m_pmh is %s" % vmd.m_pmh

        if vmd.m_pmh == 'done':
            status.append({
               'text':"No current issues were identified." ,
                'weight':2
            })
        elif vmd.m_pmh == "running":
            status.append({
                'text':'Section started, but not completed.',
                'weight':2
            })
        else:
            status.append({
                'text':'No data collected',
                'weight':2,
            })

    for t1 in status:
        t1['weight'] = string.zfill(str(t1['weight']), 4)
    #print " value of report_buckets is %s" % report_buckets
    #print " value of status is %s" % status
    #print "value of report_buckets %s " % report_buckets
    c = {'status':status}
    print "################################################"
    print c
    #return  c
    #return report_buckets
    return {
             '_report_buckets':report_buckets,
             'status':c,
    }
```

I am getting the value of c as:

```
{'status': [{'text': 'Section started, but not completed.', 'weight': '0002'}]}
```

I want to display the value of text so i wrote on my template as

```
{% load text_tools %}

Why are you not getting printed ?
{% ifequal this_section.type 'simple-report-topic' %}
    {% if status %}
        {% for group in status %}
            {% for score in group %}
                {{ score.text|capfirst }};
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endifequal %}
```

it is displaying

Why are you not getting printed ?
S
S

Why it is not entering in the loop? What template tag I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View:**

You don't need `c = {'status':status}` instead do

`return {'_report_buckets':report_buckets,'status':status}`.

**Template:**

```
{% ifequal this_section.type 'simple-report-topic' %}
    {% if status %}
        {% for score in status %}
              {{ score.text|capfirst }};
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endifequal %}
```

please don't rush, read your code you've gone wrong in the basics.

**Edit:**

Your code is trying to iterate over a `dict` which is not right. You could make your code work by simply using `{% for group in status.status %}` in your template

Comment: ya c was done because i want to know what the value it is taking i want to know what should i return i cannot use render_to_response its coming from some view and pointing to this function.so what should i write please illustrate your point .Thanks in advance which line i am wrong

Comment: you can always print `status` in my code and see what are contents

Comment: write . so i am now using  context =  in views {'_report_buckets':report_buckets,'status':status,}                                                   and in templates {% if status %}
    {% for s in status %}
        {{s.text}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %} but what should i return? please correct me !! Thanks in advance. i will appreciate that.

Comment: return the `context` by `return context` instead of `return {'_report_buckets':report_buckets,'status':status}`

Comment: i did that now in templates i am writing                             {% if status in context %}{% for group in status %}{{group.text}}{% endfor%}{% endif %} but again it is printing S S .I am really thankful please correct me i was really stuck on that.Please help

Comment: well did you `print` the `status` in your `view` what did it return?